# Materials don't seem to load in Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I am trying to load an object that i exported in Blender using the Three.js exporter (yes, i exported all materials) but they don't seem to show up when i load the object with Three.js.

This is what i get:
[chair with weird blue colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvWe0.png)

I can give the chair whatever color i want but a part of the chair always turns out some kind of weird blue or green color which i didn't chose.

Here's the JSON data:

```
"materials":[{
    "DbgIndex":1,
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "colorDiffuse":[0.68928,0.212069,0],
    "specularCoef":50,
    "shading":"phong",
    "transparent":false,
    "doubleSided":true,
    "wireframe":false,
    "depthTest":true,
    "DbgColor":15597568,
    "opacity":1,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "blending":"NormalBlending",
    "depthWrite":true,
    "DbgName":"Ch_seat",
    "visible":true
},{
    "DbgIndex":0,
    "colorSpecular":[0.454809,0.454809,0.454809],
    "colorDiffuse":[0.4878,0.471319,0.471319],
    "specularCoef":74,
    "shading":"phong",
    "transparent":false,
    "doubleSided":true,
    "wireframe":false,
    "depthTest":true,
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "opacity":1,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "blending":"NormalBlending",
    "depthWrite":true,
    "DbgName":"Ch_leg",
    "visible":true
}],
```

There should be one material for the seat and one for the legs.

I'm loading it like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('./frontend/base/img/chair.json', function(geometry, materials) {
    console.log(geometry, materials);
    var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.translation = geometry.center(geometry);
    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 8;
    scene.add(mesh);
    render();
});
```

So what's going wrong here? Am i forgetting something?

Comment: I don't know if you fixed this, but I was able to get materials to finally show up in blender exported .json files by using Blender Render instead of cycles, and you have to make the material / texture appear in the viewport for it to export properly. Not really sure what is up with the exporter, but it sets the viewport material as the exported material.